# Enchanting a tapped land

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When enchanting a tapped land using [New Horizons](https://scryfall.com/card/jmp/414/new-horizons) can I still produce mana using it or do I have to wait for my next turn?

Knowing that the enchantment let's you produce 2 mana when tapping the enchanted land, since I enchanted a tapped land that already produced 1 mana, but can I produce 1 more mana after enchanted that tapped land that already produced 1 mana?

I'm not sure if can't produce any mana, produce 1 mana, or produce 2 mana.

Answer (score 11):

**You need to wait until the land untaps to get more mana from it.**

Lands generally have abilities that allow you to tap them to produce mana. New Horizons gives the land a different ability that also allows you to tap it to produce mana. If the land is already tapped, you can't use any abilities that require you to tap it until it untaps.

Basic lands (Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, Forest) and other lands with basic land types automatically have an ability "{T}: Add {M}" where M is the corresponding color of mana, as a result of [rule 305.6](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Land). Most other lands explicitly have similar abilities printed on them.

Comment: Might want to note that the rules add "{T}: Add {C}" abilities to lands with the subtype(s) Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, Forest, with basics often just having a big {C} instead of a text box

Comment: @Caleth, based on questions like this, it comes to mind that the decision not to print the ability in full on basic lands must be one of the most confusing and misleading decisions made by game makers...

Comment: also could underline that they don't need to wait for _the next turn_ in particular, just for the land to untap. If they can do that for one mana, then there's that one mana net gain available.

Comment: @ilkkachu I say that in bold in the first sentence. How much more emphasis do you think it needs?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wait until its untapped to get more mana from it.

---

You seem to be under the misconception that Basic Lands give mana when tapped. This is not accurate. Basic Lands give mana as the result of using their intrinsic activated ability. Using this ability requires tapping the land, but it's not tapping the land that gives the mana, it's activating the ability. For example, using [Twiddle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Twiddle) to tap a Basic Land would not generate mana.

In your scenario, the ability that granted the mana has long since resolved. There's nothing you can do now that will change the amount of mana it gave.

And the newly granted ability won't produce any mana until its activated. To activate the new ability, you need to tap the land, which you can't do if it's already tapped.

Either way, the new ability will never grant just one mana. The instructions clearly say you add two mana to your mana pool, not just one.

Comment: Worth noting the land will still have the existing intrinsic ability, the new one doesn't replace it, but since the removal of mana burn there won't be any situation where it's worthwhile to use the old ability - the land still CAN tap for one mana of that original single color.